# React to change failures in a pure presentational component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a pure component that display a type of entity. The component allows the user to interact and make changes to the entity, however these changes may be rejected by the server. In this case, I want the component to do an animation to display to the user that the change failed.

I can add another input to the component for a boolean, that the parent *smart* component would flip to 'on' when the animation is desired, but it seems like a leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using content projection, similar to how Angular Material deals with the `mat-error`

In your smart / container component, you'll have something like:

```html
<my-presentation-component>
  <div my-presentation-error *ngIf="hasError">This is the error</div>
</my-presentation-component>
```

In your presentation component:

```html
<div>
  <!-- mark-up for your component -->
  <ng-content select="[my-presentation-error]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

A guide on [ng-content](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/)

Comment: thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, it still breaks the abstraction

Comment: could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure. It makes me place error views from outside the component

Comment: A presentation component wouldn't know what error to show, or what error message to show. You should just be able to "send" it an error to display. This is the way most component libraries are built.